# R: invalid multibyte string 1 (with spread)

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I'm trying to spread two columns but R is returning

```
Error in make.names(x) : invalid multibyte string 1
```

There are plenty of questions here and elsewhere about invalid multibyte strings, but they are all for reading files into R; the issue seems to always be about encoding. Here, though, I already have my file read into R and it is only when spreading that I run into the issue.

I cannot reproduce the problem but here is my code:

```
df <- spread(df, Var1, Var2)
```

Comment: I've found that R is actually still doing the spread, it just returns the error as well. I can't call the new df but it appears in my environment and I can partially work with it (I can call `names(df)` but I can't view it)

Comment: can you please include sample code that you are using so we can reproduce this? Also, what are the new colnames generated by spread?